# OWA IE issue with Calendar Event editor and Outlook add-in

Tags: internet-explorer-11, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-app

It looks like a bug has popped up with OWA for Internet Explorer 11. If you open an add-in's task pane within the calendar event editor, then you will lose the ability to create events until you restart OWA. This issue does not occur in OWA using Edge, Chrome or Firefox.

We encountered this with our add-in but after testing concluded that it would occur with other add-ins which have a task pane for editing a calendar invite. For example it occurs when using Microsoft's "My Templates" add-in with our add-in not installed.

To reproduce the issue try the following:

1. Open OWA in Internet Explorer 11.
2. Select "Create event". The event editor opens.
3. Open Microsoft's "My Templates" or another add-in that has a task pane that opens in the event editor.
4. Close the editor window, discarding all your changes or edit and send the event.
5. Again select "Create event". Nothing will happen.
6. If you try to close IE you will get a pop-up stating "You'll lose all the changes you made."
7. If you choose "Leave this page" and close OWA, when you reopen it you will again be able to create events.

It appears like once the issue is triggered, selecting "Create event" opens the editor hidden or behind the main window. To support this hypothesis, you will observe one instance of the "You'll lose all the changes you made." for each time you select "Create event" after the issue is triggered.

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround? Can others reproduce this issue with "My Templates" or other add-ins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. This is a known issue with the Add-ins platform; we are working on a solution for this and will update once the fix has been made.

Comment: The issue has been fixed. You should be able to see the change in a few weeks.